# For a Python module, what are the standard global variables to declare?

Tags: python

In reading other Python modules, I've seen that many people often include `__version__` and `__author__` global variables in their source files (its even mentioned in [PEP3001](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3001/)).  I'd like to document my code with a reasonable set of these variables.  What is a list of global variables that might be commonly included?

Comment: Personally, I avoid cluttering my modules with any of that stuff simply for the reason that `__....__` names belong to *python* and I don't think the user should overwrite any of that stuff unless it's for a reason described in the docs (e.g `__init__` for initializing classes) ... If at some point it becomes standardized (In a PEP or the docs), I might change my opinion though

Comment: You point out PEP3001, but notice that that PEP ("Python Enhancment _Proposal_") was "Withdrawn". Therefore, the language of the PEP shouldn't be considered as a "standard". You might have just missed the status flag, but just in case, I'll include the link to [PEP 1](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/), which explains how the PEP process works.

Comment: @mgilson - This is a fair comment.  I like the idea of having "self-documenting" code, even if its just hardly-standardized global variables.  But, at the same time, I see where you are coming from since `__...__` does belong to Python.

Comment: @MarkHildreth - Yup, missed that flag. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @WilliBallenthin -- Yeah, I like that idea as well.  I suppose I'm not taking issue with the idea -- rather the implementation.  Until Guido and communtiy come to a consensus on this one, I'd add a function to the API with returns a dictionary that holds this information (or rely on the meta-data that setuptools/distribute/distutils adds as the other posters have alluded to)

Answer (score 3):

There isn't a specific standard for those global variables - as noted in the PEP you linked, they were attempts to achieve a standard but haven't become universally accepted in any singular form.

The real standard is the PyPI metadata, which is specified in the `setup.py` file for your module, using `distutils` (or a compatible interface). Here's the example from the packaging tutorial:

```
from distutils.core import setup

setup(
    name='TowelStuff',
    version='0.1.0',
    author='J. Random Hacker',
    author_email='jrh@example.com',
    packages=['towelstuff', 'towelstuff.test'],
    scripts=['bin/stowe-towels.py','bin/wash-towels.py'],
    url='http://pypi.python.org/pypi/TowelStuff/',
    license='LICENSE.txt',
    description='Useful towel-related stuff.',
    long_description=open('README.txt').read(),
    install_requires=[
        "Django >= 1.1.1",
        "caldav == 0.1.4",
    ],
)
```

http://guide.python-distribute.org/creation.html

Comment: Note that (IIUC) distutils is on the way out. For example, `setup(...)` is to be replaced by static metadata in `setup.cfg`. I have absolutely no idea how close this is to becoming reality though.

Answer (score 2):

Use `distutils` (or the superset `setuptools`) instead to provide metadata about your project.

Especially when using `setuptools`, that metadata is then discoverable and reusable through the [`pkg_resources` module](https://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/pkg_resources.html).

There is no standard for global variables such as `__version__`, not even for the Python stdlib, which is why the effort to provide this metadata in the stdlib for Python 3 has not amounted to anything.

I can recommend the [Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/) as a primer on how to package your project properly.

Comment: *the effort to provide this metadata in the stdlib for Python 3 has not amounted to anything* – could you please provide some reference? Also, you might be able to explain why some stdlib packages have metadata and others do not — see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/1570

Comment: See https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-dev/2012-June/120430.html; `distutils2` never gained enough traction and with it the new metadata formats and efforts. As for metadata in *some* stdlib libraries: I guess they were first independent projects that have since been merged into the stdlib.